# Building variable in batch file from FOR loop

Tags: batch-file

I would like to build a string for use as an argument in a command line utility. The string will be built from the presence of certain services which I have defined in a variable. I have the following code so far:

`@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "PRODS=Service1 Service2 Service3"
REM Let's see what's installed.
SET NEWPRODS=
FOR %%i in (%PRODS%) DO (
  %comspec% /c %WINDIR%\system32\sc.exe query %%i | %WINDIR%\system32\findstr /C:"RUNNING">nul 
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    SET NEWPRODS=%%i
    ECHO !NEWPRODS!
  )
)`

How do I make the output (let's assume that service 1 and 3 is found and is running) to be like so: Service1,Service3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want the variable `NEWPRODS` to hold a string like `Service1,Service3` literally?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I just need a delimited list of services which are found and running, from the list I specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "PRODS=Service1 Service2 Service3"
REM Let's see what's installed.
SET "NEWPRODS="
FOR %%i in (%PRODS%) DO sc.exe query %%i | findstr /C:"RUNNING">nul && SET "NEWPRODS=!NEWPRODS!%%i,"

REM Trim trailing comma if string is not empty
IF NOT "%NEWPRODS%"=="" SET "NEWPRODS=%NEWPRODS:~0,-1%"
ECHO(%NEWPRODS%
pause
```

Don't do

```
echo %SomeVariable%
```

If the variable is blank it will display the current ECHO state.
Use quotes when setting strings so you don't get any unintended spaces.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this doesn't populate the variable with the values I expect (or even at all)--even without the Trim section.

Comment: It works for me. Presumably you replaced Service1-3 with legitimate service names and they are running???

Comment: You're right. I didn't replace the service names to what they should have been after scrubbing them for the post. Your solution does indeed work and, again, thank you!

Comment: Great! Your welcome. We've all made that mistake :) Please mark as answer if you are satisfied with it.